# the fundamental solution of heat equations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let 
$$\Phi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-x^2/4t}$$
be the fundamental solution of the heat equation (or the heat kernel).

What is the supremum of $\Phi$ over $x$:
$$\sup_x \Phi(x,t)?$$

Comment: It's not hard to see that it occurs at $x=0$.

Comment: First, $|\Phi(x,t)|\ne \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$.  Rather, $|\Phi(x,t)|=\Phi(x,t)$ since $\Phi(x,t)$ is non-negative. Second, the least upper bound over $x$ is simply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just realised...so in conclusion, $\sup_x\Phi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, we have $\exp(\xi) < 1$ for $\xi < 0$ and $\exp(0) = 1$. Hence, for every $x \ne 0$, we have 
$$ \Phi(x,t) = \frac 1{(4\pi t)^{1/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right) 
  < \frac 1{(4\pi t)^{1/2}} $$
As 
$$ \Phi(0, t) = \frac 1{(4\pi t)^{1/2}}$$
we have that 
$$ \sup_{x\in \mathbf R} \Phi(x,t) = \frac 1{(4\pi t)^{1/2}} $$